# Time complexity Recursive program

Tags: time-complexity

I can't figure out the time complexety of the following snippet of code:

```
void  f( int N ){
   sum ++;
   if ( N   > 1){
      f( N /2);
      f( N /2);
   }
```

It's the double iteration that gives me problems.

I know (or think) that the time complexity of

```
void  f( int N ){
   sum ++;
   if ( N   > 1){
      f( N /2);
   }
```

is ~log2(N) but don't know what to do with the other code.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but see if you can work out the function for a few small inputs.  Maybe the complexity will be obvious to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try tracing through it:

**Let N be 8**.

1 + f(4) + f(4)

=> 1 + 2 + f(2) + f(2) + f(2) + f(2)

=> 1 + 6 + f(1) + f(1) + f(1) + f(1) + f(1) + f(1) + f(1) + f(1)

*When n = 8; work = 15*

**Let N be 4**.

1 + f(2) + f(2)

=> 1 + 2 + f(1) + f(1) + f(1) + f(1)

*When n = 4; work = 7*

**Let N be 2**

1 + f(1) + f(1)

*When n = 2; work = 3;*

**Let N be 1**

1

*When n = 1; work = 1*

---

So at a glance the work pattern seems to be **2n - 1**

We still need to prove it!

From the algorithm the recursive relation is:

W(1) = 1
W(N) = 1 + 2 * W(N / 2)

**Proof by induction**

*Base Case:*

W(1) = 2(1) - 1 = 1 *as required*.

*Recursive case:*

*Assume W(N / 2) = 2(n/2) - 1 = n - 1*

W(N) = 1 + 2 * (N / 2)

*Applying induction...*

W(N) = 1 + 2(n - 1) = 1 + 2n - 2 = 2n - 1 *as required*

---

Therefore the complexity is **O(2n - 1)** because *O is reflexive*

=> **O( max { 2n, -1 } )** because of the *rule of sums*

=> **O(2n)**

=> **O(n)** because of the *rule of scaling*

Comment: thanks you. Just to be sure, is my solution to the second problem correct?

Comment: n = 16, w = 5; n = 8, w = 4; n = 4, w = 3; n = 2, w = 2; ---> It looks logarithmic to me

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the recursion twice on `(N/2)`. Lets write the formula:

```
T(n) = 2*(N/2) + 1
```

Using [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem), we fall on the first case where:

- **a=2**
- **f = O(1)**
- **b=2**

---

```
T(n) = Θ(n)
```

---

We also find **T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + 1** [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Application_to_common_algorithms), which shows it is bounded by `O(n)`

Answer (score 3):

A good way to solve this problem would be:

---

*1. Finding the recurrence relation*

For each call to `f` we have time complexity `T(N)`. Each call contains:

- A constant amount of work `C`: `sum++`, comparison `N > 1`, recursive calling overhead, etc.
- 2 recursive calls to `f`, each with time complexity `T(N / 2)`.

Thus the *recurrence relation* is given by `T(N) = 2T(N/2) + C`.

---

*2. Finding a solution by inspection*

If we repeatedly substitute `T(N)` into itself, we can see an emerging pattern:

[image]

What is the upper limit of the summation, `m`? Since the stopping condition is `N > 1`, after repeated substitutions the requirement would be

[image]

Thus the summation equals (dropping the round-down, and the constant `C` because it is simply multiplicative):

[image]

---

*3. Proof by induction*

- Base step: test if the summation result is correct for the lowest possible value of `N`, i.e. 2:

  [image]

  The result is consistent.
- Recurrence step: confirm that if the summation is correct for `N / 2`, it is also correct for `N`:

  [image]

  Which is exactly our original recurrence relation.

Hence by induction, the summation result is correct, and `T(N)` is indeed `Ө(N)`.

---

*4. Numerical testing:*

We can write code to confirm our result if needed:

```
function T(n) {
  return n > 1 ? 2 * T(floor(n/2)) + 1 : 1;
}
```

Results:

```
N           T(N)
-------------------------
2           3
4           7
8           15
16          31
32          63
64          127
128         255
256         511
512         1023
1024        2047
2048        4095
4096        8191
8192        16383
16384       32767
32768       65535
65536       131071
131072      262143
262144      524287
524288      1048575
1048576     2097151
2097152     4194303
4194304     8388607
8388608     16777215
16777216    33554431
33554432    67108863
67108864    134217727
134217728   268435455
268435456   536870911
536870912   1073741823
1073741824  2147483647
```

Graph:

[image]

Comment: Your answers are not appreciated as they should be. Very good and detailed answer! +1.

Comment: @TonyTannous thanks. Your's too - using the master theorem in a simple situation like this is probably the better way to go than proving from scratch

Answer (score 0):

This code is much similar to **binary tree traversal**,

```
void  f( int N ){
   sum ++;
   if ( N   > 1){
      f( N /2);  //like Traverse left subtree
      f( N /2);  //like Traverse right subtree
   }
```

which basically traverses through each node once, with `O(N)` time complexity.

```
                    n/8
             n/4   --------- 
                    n/8
      n/2   ------------------    

                    n/8
             n/4  ---------
                    n/8

n -------------------------------
                    n/8
             n/4    --------- 
                    n/8
      n/2   ----------------

                    n/8
             n/4   ---------
                    n/8
```

this goes on till the passed value becomes 1 or 0.